# Css Flexbox Navbar Right Align

Tags: html, css, flexbox

basically what I am trying to do is to implement a navigator in css without using float/clearfix. Instead I am using a better approach, css3's flexbox.
I know it's simple to align items to the left easily but what's the optimal solutions for having a narbar which has two aligned regions ?

Something like:

[Home]-[Stuff]------------[Credits]-[About]

This was my attempt implementing this:

https://jsfiddle.net/asss321/ornontbt/

Basically the idea is to wrap two flexboxes into one and set the right flexbox to:

```
.child.child-right {
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Is this a good way to do it ? Or I am using some hacky way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your way is not a bad one. However, using nested elements may be unnecessary.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.container > :nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: auto;
}
a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Start</a>
  <a href="#">Extra</a>
  <a href="#">Credits</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for suggesting another way of doing this but I think the solution should be more generic. So it should be dynamically set in the html code where the a tags should be aligned right. Something like in bootstrap where we can use the navbar-right class.

Comment: Just set a class on the first element aligned right, and in that class set margin-left: auto

Answer (score 0):

So for moving the nav items to the right in the Navbar component, we can use CSS flexbox properties for the same. The basic approach whenever you encounter any situation like this is to find it's parent element.
[Here the parent element, in this code is "header" which has a logo and some nav-items. For shifting nav-items to right, we will apply "justify-content: space-between;" to the header. This will push nav-items to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaUuu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide textual information as text, not as picture of text.